# Can I use the Shining Trapezohedron against Epic Monsters to attempt to move them?

Tags: eldritch-horror, eldritch-horror-under-the-pyramids

The trapezohedron allows the investigator to discard the chosen monster on a roll of 5 or 6. Since discarding Epic Monsters is disallowed, would a 5 or 6 result in no action while a roll of 1-4 result in moving the monster to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact text on the card is:

[image: Shining Trapezohedrom]

> **Action:** Choose 1 Monster on any space and role 1 die. On a 5 or 6, discard that Monster. On a 1-4, move that Monster to your space.

[From the reference guide (page 6):](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/39/c1/39c182c1-6b0d-46c4-b5eb-dd6886b4c798/eh01_reference_guide1.pdf)

> Epic Monsters are treated like Monsters for all effects except as described here:
>
> - An Epic Monster cannot be defeated by any effect except losing Health equal to or greater than it's toughness.
>     An Epic Monster cannot be discarded.
> - **An Epic Monster cannot be moved, except by an effect on its 
>     token or the component that spawned it.**
> - Epic Monsters are never placed in the Monster cup.
> - When an Epic Monster is defeated, it is returned to the game box.
> - “Monster” refers to a Monster and/or an Epic Monsters. “Non-Epic Monster” refers to a Monster but not an Epic Monster.

So no, the Shining Trapezohedron can not move the Epic Monster